# Java - Set Password after Validating

Tags: java

I need to reference `isValidPassword(String pw)` 
and when true set the password (pw) in the method `setPassword(String pw)`

and also print the line "The password works"

else print out "Try again"

my code so far is:

```
public void setPassword(String pw) {
    if (this.isValidPassword(pw)) {
        this.password = pw;
        System.out.println("The password works");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does this code not work?

Comment: You should most likely call `isValidPassword()` outside of `setPassword()`, based on your description on how it should work. Do not call it inside the `setPassword()` method and don't write the `System.out.println()` lines inside the `setPassword()` method as well.

Comment: @J.Doe2nd Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have AND add the full assignment to your question as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replys. I need to reference `isValidPassword()` inside the method `setPassword()`. At the moment its going straight to the `else` and not checking to see if the password is valid.

Comment: @J.Doe2nd No, by the code you posted, it's first checking if the password is valid and then, if it's not valid, it's going to the else.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method which you can modify and use. Of course the password can be used as a hardcoded string or you can use a Scanner and entry this password. This is only an example.

```
 public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

         PasswordEx ps = new PasswordEx();

        String password = "abcdef";

        ps.setPassword(password);

     }
}

class PasswordEx {

    private String password;

    public PasswordEx() {
    }

    private boolean isValidPassword(String password) {
         if (password.length() >= 8) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     }

     public void setPassword(String password) {
         if (isValidPassword(password)) {
             this.password = password;
         } else {
             System.out.println("Your password is not valid!");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: the `setPassword(String password)` in this example code is almost identical to mine and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That works, sorry but I wrote it quickly using online editor, so in previous version could be some mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for that but the bit i need to work is still the same as mine. the `setPassword` method

Comment: still can't get this..anyone?